# Can't use shorthand arrow function

Tags: javascript

```
gulp.task('devInject', ['styles', 'devScripts'], () => {
  return inject();
});
```

I'm getting a linting error: `requireShorthandArrowFunctions` ref:http://jscs.info/rule/requireShorthandArrowFunctions

However, when I attempt to use the shorthand, I get an error:

```
gulp.task('devInject', ['styles', 'devScripts'], () => return inject(); );
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token return

How am I supposed to write the shorthand?

Comment: It should be `, () => inject() );`

Comment: delete return keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify `return` if you're using the shorthand arrow syntax, as it will implicitly return the result of the expression on the right hand side.

```
gulp.task('devInject', ['styles', 'devScripts'], () => inject());
```

Of course, this means if you ever want to extend the arrow function to have multiple expressions, you'll have to add the `{` and `}` back in and use an explicit return statement.

Answer (score 2):

With es6, using the shorthand, the return is implied. You should be able to say

```
gulp.task('devInject', ['styles', 'devScripts'], () => inject() );
```